# URL Path exclude certain sting in regular expression for rewrite rule

Tags: regex

How to modify below regular expression  for any path start with **/a/**, but  excluding string **/dk/**

```
(^/a/(.*)$)
```

so that **/a/remove** can match, but **/a/dk/** remove won't

Comment: further more, if we also don't want to match /a/fl/remove

Answer (score 0):

```
(^(?!.*(?:/dk/|/fl/))/a/(.*)$)
```

You can add `lookahead` for the same.